# Programming a bot to place a block

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m trying to get my MineFlayer bot to place a sand block on the face of a piston when it detects it in a 5 block radius.

I’ve already tried bot.placeblock(33, vec(0,0,1), cb) and it gives me a error “offset”.

```
Bot.PlaceBlock(blockID, vec(1,0,0), cb)
```

Here is the mineflayer github source code https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer

The API is in docs

It’s suppose to place a block on the sides of pistons in a 5 block radius.
But I just get errors and can’t get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us better understand the problem you're having you'll need to be very specific about the error message you're getting, make sure to copy-paste the *exact error text* into your question. It's also important to give us enough code for context we can try and reproduce the problem if necessary. It's not clear what the error is here, nor where it actually occurs in your code. Remember JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, so instead of just randomly flipping around the case, read the source for examples and use cases.

Answer (score 1):

placeBlock takes a block instance as reference, not an ID. In order to use placeBlock you will need to do the following:

1. Put the block you want to place in your hotbar (`bot.moveSlotItem`)
2. Select that slot for your hand (`bot.equip`)
3. Get the block instance (possibly from `blockAt`, or from `findBlock`)
4. Now you can call `placeBlock(block, face, cb)`

See https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/6ae68d3bc754ac165e658cd8c64ce32e22a1706f/lib/plugins/inventory.js#L319 for the reason you're getting the error (I'm assuming "cannot read property 'offset' of undefined", because .position is undefined for the ID, a number), and https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/docs/api.md for other API information regarding what I've said.

edit: here is an excerpt of some code that would roughly accomplish this

```
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({ /* ... */ });

// ... do some action that would get you within range of a piston ...

// This .findBlock method will find the nearest block to the point, which is the position of the bot's entity. The block it finds must match the piston block ID, and will be returned.
const piston = bot.findBlock({ point: bot.entity.position, matching: pistonBlockId });  

if (piston == null) {
  return;
}

// the null is required for some reason, but doesn't do anything
const sand = bot.inventory.findInventoryItem(sandBlockId, null);

if (sand == null) {
  return;
}

const onSandPlace = (error) => // ...

const onSandEquip = (error) => {
  if (error) {
    return;
  }

  // this vec should probably be different based on the face you want to place it on
  bot.placeBlock(piston, new Vec3(0, 1, 0), onSandPlace);
}

bot.equip(sand, 'hand', onSandEquip);
```

This code is missing a few things:

1. Figuring out which face to place on the piston (I think you would need to look into metadata values for the piston, it should be in the `piston` var)
2. Actually getting near a piston, or finding the sand to equip
3. Waiting until the bot is able to do things (i.e. waiting for the join event)

Comment: I don’t quite understand :/ I’m really new to this, could you give me an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added a code snippet above which should help you out (it was too long to comment)

Comment: Ok so Thanks for you help, but the const  onSandPlace = (error) => //... makes const onSandPlace = (error) => { if (error) { return;} part not work. So if I remove const onSandPlace = (error) => //... it still doesn’t work even after replacing pistonBlockID and sandBlockId, still doesn’t work without replacing sandBlockID

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. What did you put inside of your onSandPlace method?

Comment: No the 1st const onSandPlace make it so that the second const didnt work. And got a error const unexpected

Comment: A friend told to try something with .catch

Comment: None of these methods return promises, catch isn't going to help you at all. Did you actually finish the method for onSandPlace? I left it intentionally empty since I have no idea what you wanted in it